Why can't VS code generate the PlantUML folder automatically after installing the CSharp to PlantUML plugin?
Currently using:
.NET 8.0 Runtime
CSharp to PlantUML 1.4.0.
VS code 1.90.1
Node.js: 20.9.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Following the steps in the video (2:16), I am unable to generate the PlantUML folder in EXPLORER. How can I solve this problem?



